# TS cannot infer function return type on its own

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider:

```js
const fcts = {
  fctNumber: () => 1,
  fctBoolean: () => true,
}
```

as expected, a function that simply selects from `fcts` returns the correct type based on the value of `T`

```js
const getFct = <T extends keyof typeof fcts>(name: T) => {
  return fcts[name]
}

getFct('fctNumber') // () => number
getFct('fctBoolean') // () => boolean
```

The same function but returning the *result* of calling the selected function is expected to return the return type of the selected function, but TS instead infers `number | boolean`

```js
const getResult = <T extends keyof typeof fcts>(name: T) => {
  const fct = fcts[name]
  return fct()
}

getResult('fctNumber') // expected number, got number | boolean
getResult('fctBoolean') // expected boolean, got number | boolean
```

Changing the last line to add what seems like a redundant assertion works:

```js
return fct() as ReturnType<typeof fct>
```

...but why? that doesn't seem to be adding any new information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript cannot perform the kind of higher order analysis needed to maintain the correlation between the type of `name` (a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K`) and the return type of `fcts[name]`.  It doesn't "see" `fcts` as an object of zero-arg functions which returns a type correlated with the type of `name`.  When evaluating the type `(typeof fcts)[K]` as a callable function, the compiler first widens it to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is `(typeof fcts)[keyof typeof fcts]`, and becomes the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `(() => number) | (() => boolean)`.  And once that happens there's no hope, since TypeScript can't do much with correlated union types either.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

If you don't want to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for expedience, you could try refactoring as recommended in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  What we need is for `fcts` to be of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like `{ [K in keyof FctsReturn]: () => FctsReturn[K] }` for an appropriately-defined `FctsReturn`.  Then `fcts[name]` would be a single function of type `() => FctsReturn[K]`, and calling it would result in `FctsReturn[K]`.  No union involved.

You can use your existing code to derive `FctsReturn`, such as by renaming `fcts` out of the way (to, say, `_fcts`), computing `FctsReturn` using the [`ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), and then giving `fcts` the necessary type annotation:

```
const _fcts = {
    fctNumber: () => 1,
    fctBoolean: () => true,
}
type FctsReturn = { [K in keyof typeof _fcts]: ReturnType<typeof _fcts[K]> };
const fcts: { [K in keyof FctsReturn]: () => FctsReturn[K] } = _fcts;
```

This looks like a roundabout way of doing nothing; surely the type of `fcts` is equivalent either way. But since the compiler cannot automatically "see" how to distribute `ReturnType<T>` across the elements of `fcts`, you have to do it yourself.  Now this works:

```
const getResult = <K extends keyof FctsReturn>(name: K) => {
    const fct = fcts[name]
    return fct()
}

const num = getResult('fctNumber');
//    ^? const num: number

const boo = getResult('fctBoolean');
//    ^? const boo: boolean
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gM2FCMC8MDeAoGeZJQByArgLYBGApgE4BcMAFAJToB8MAjADS76EAhECAA2VAIZgGLdjCg0SVXgF9sUAJ4AHKjABiyCACUqUEjTDosMANoBpGAEsLAayrqQCOVqof4hCAC6DMam5gAq3gA8Gtq+iAZ2ARzKANzYoJCw-gyYNvZOMK7unvooIWZgQUysaBylRiYViTDKlvEoaeng0DAA5ibGECQisBiR9lQAHlBUYAAmqEW+9eXmbIxg4mRUDLY1HDj4MBk9hJb+1pvbAXx4NI3mBMgs2KpdmTBg5Jb9UIPDUEYAHJCKRKLQgcw0gB6aFHAB6AH5sO8ehRhD8BlQhiNgYJhGJJJCYXD8EigA)

Answer (score 0):

The type gets lost here:

```
const getResult = <T extends keyof typeof fcts>(name: T) => {
  const fct = fcts[name]
  let result = fct()
  //  ^?
  // let result: number | boolean
  return result
}
```

You may do

```
const getResult = <T extends keyof typeof fcts>(name: T) => {
  const fct = fcts[name]
  let result = fct() as ReturnType<typeof fct>
  //  ^?
  //   let result: ReturnType<{
  //     fctNumber: () => number;
  //     fctBoolean: () => boolean;
  //   }[T]>
  return result
}
```

then it'll work

Comment: Why it gets lost there I dunno ask someone esle